# Loading something in R

Tags: r, load, workspace

After trying to load a data space (R) which is named

```
in_r 2 RDat
```

if I do

```
load("in_r 2 RDat")
```

it works and the table `seq` has dim (20,30) which it should. If I do

```
paste("in_r",i,"RDat")->s
load(s)->seq

dim(seq)
# NULL
```

how can that be ? I tried several times in different R versions (3.1.3 and 3.1.1)

Comment: Works for me. `x <- 1:10; s <- paste("in_r", 2, "RDat"); save(x, file = s); rm(list = ls()); s <- paste("in_r", 2, "RDat"); load(s)`

Comment: I fail to see why this has been closed. The post contains the desired behavior (value of dim after loading), the specific error problem (dim is NULL), and a code that reproduces the error.

Comment: The only thing that is missing is the definition of seq, but it is stated that it is a 20x30 matrix or data.frame, and neither the values nor the class of the variable are important here.

Answer (score 1):

You should not assign the output of `load()` to a variable. The name of the stored object is available as you load it. Therefore, instead of

```
load(s) -> seq
```

just use

```
load(s)
```

and the object with the name `seq` is available in the environment, provided that this is the name of what was stored in `in_r 2 RDat`.